# python saving certain http response json values into file

Tags: python, api, rest

I am running a query against an API of the following

[https://test.url/api/v2/services/level/app?domainname={}&offset=0&limit=100](https://test.url/api/v2/services/level/app?domainname=%7B%7D&offset=0&limit=100)

I am getting the domains from a txt file called domains.txt

```
with open('domains.txt') as f_input:
for id in f_input:
    url = "https://test.url/api/v2/services/level/app?domainname={}&offset=0&limit=100".format(id.strip())
    resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept':'application/json','Api-Token': 'XXXX'})
    json_string = json.dumps(resp.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    print(json_string)
```

the domains.txt contains

```
url1.com
url2.com
url3.com
```

in my response I am getting the following:

```
    "data": [
    {
        "app_name": "App1",
        "category_name": "Category1",
        "level": 44,
        "indicator": "poor",
        "id": 9563
    }
],
"status": "Success",
"status_code": 200,
"total_query_count": 1
```

}

I now want to write the App_name alongside the Category together with the corresponding URLs from domain.txt into a new text file so that eventually I end up with

URL1 App_Name Category

I am trying getting the category and the app_name dumped into a file but I am struggling

```
with open("ergebnis.txt", "w") as f:
  for i in list['data']:
    f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(i["app_name"],str(i["category_name"])))
```

I am getting

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/test/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    for i in list['data']:
TypeError: 'types.GenericAlias' object is not iterable
```

Can anybody help me writing (and perhaps merging) URL App_Name and Category in a file?

EDIT:

```
with open('domains.txt') as f_input:
for id in f_input:
    url = "https://test.url/api/v2/services/level/app?domainname={}&offset=0&limit=100".format(id.strip())
    resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept':'application/json','Api-Token': 'XXX'})
    # json_string = json.dumps(resp.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    resp_json = resp.json()
    for i in resp_json["data"]:
        with open("ergebnis.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(i["app_name"],str(i["category_name"])))
```

made it work, I am now getting both the app_name and category_name in each line.

thank you

Comment: Can you show in the code where you are assigning the variable "list" ? My guess is you converted it to a string instead of a dict

Comment: this is indeed my full code, I was not assigning variable list indeed.

Answer (score 0):

change `for i in list['data']:` to `for i in resp.json()['data']:`.

Comment: now it doesnt throw any error but the file is still empty

Comment: what's the complete output of `resp.json()` ?

Comment: see my edit, it worked this way. thanks Anwar

Answer (score 0):

what is `list` in this code block:

```
with open("ergebnis.txt", "w") as f:
  for i in list['data']:
    f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(i["app_name"],str(i["category_name"])))
```

based on the code you provided most likely you need to iterate through the json response:

```
with open('domains.txt') as f_input:
for id in f_input:
    url = "https://test.url/api/v2/services/level/app?domainname={}&offset=0&limit=100".format(id.strip())
    resp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept':'application/json','Api-Token': 'XXXX'})
     
    resp_json = resp.json()
    for i in resp_json["data"]:
        ...
```

P.S. best to avoid naming variables with names used for built-in python functions or types (e.g. `list`)